# Auto select with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Html code:

```
        <div class="per-input per-businessHour">
                    <select name="closing_time[]" class="closing_time close_time" id="closing_time1">
                      <option value="">Choose</option>
                      @if ($range = range(strtotime('00:00'),strtotime('23:59'),15*60))
                        @foreach ($range as $time)
                          <option value="{{ date('h:i A',$time) }}">{{ date('h:i A',$time) }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                      @endif
                    </select>
                    <span value="1" class="editTime">Edit</span>
                  </div>
        <div class="per-input per-businessHour">
                    <select name="closing_time[]" class="closing_time close_time" id="closing_time2">
                      <option value="">Choose</option>
                      @if ($range = range(strtotime('00:00'),strtotime('23:59'),15*60))
                        @foreach ($range as $time)
                          <option value="{{ date('h:i A',$time) }}">{{ date('h:i A',$time) }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                      @endif
                    </select>
                    <span value="2" class="editTime">Edit</span>
                  </div>
        <div class="per-input per-businessHour">
                    <select name="closing_time[]" class="closing_time close_time" id="closing_time3">
                      <option value="">Choose</option>
                      @if ($range = range(strtotime('00:00'),strtotime('23:59'),15*60))
                        @foreach ($range as $time)
                          <option value="{{ date('h:i A',$time) }}">{{ date('h:i A',$time) }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                      @endif
                    </select>
                    <span value="3" class="editTime">Edit</span>
                  </div>
```

jQuery code:

```
    $('.closing_time').on('change', function () {
      for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        $('#closing_time'+i).find('option[value="'+this.value+'"]').attr("selected",true);
      }
    })

    $('.editTime').on('click', function () {
      var id = $(this).attr('value');
      $('#closing_time'+id).removeClass('close_time');
      $('#closing_time'+id).removeClass('closing_time');
      $('#closing_time'+id).addClass('editclose_time');
      $('#closing_time'+id).removeAttr('id');
      $('#closing_time'+id).find('option[value=""]').attr("selected",false);
    })
    $('.editclose_time').on('change', function () {
      $('.editclose_time').find('option[value="'+this.value+'"]').attr("selected",true);
    })
```

I am trying like this:
If i select one of this all select value then all select option value will be selected as same. On special condition if i try to edit specific select option, wanting change only this select value and selected option.. not all of this. But failed to do this...It changed all of the select value and selected option. If anybody help me on this, Please

Comment: You don't need a loop. Just `$(".closing_time").val(this.value)`

Comment: What is the "special condition"?

Comment: on click edit for specific select tag-- "special condition"

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$(".per-businessHour").on("change", ".closing_time", function() {
    $(".closing_time").val(this.value);
});
```

This uses event delegation, so dynamically changing the classes changes whether the event handler runs. When you click on the Edit button, it removes the `closing_time` class, so this code won't run when you select from it. It also uses that class to find the other selects to update.